# How to render input field with on change method using local state in react? here its work but every time he use initial array to store value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Its is to set question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDRcK.png)

[here we show preview and tack answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rwqe.png)

Comment: What did you try? Paste some code here with what you tried.

Comment: There are a lot of examples of using state with form inputs, please include a specific challenge you are facing with or examples of what you've tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.